lock free queue's memory order choices
I have read the description of release-consume ordering, but I still have some confusion about this implementation of a lock free queue.
My high level understanding is the primary goal to prevent head_ and tail_ from "crossing". However, I don’t understand the specifics.
I suppose this crossing can happen two ways--one: push() could accidentally overfill the queue and increase tail_ too far, right on top of where head_ currently is. How does head_.load(std::memory_order_acquire) prevent this?
The other way crossing could occur: pop() could accidentally try to remove elements and increase head_ too far even though it's empty? head_ seems to be treated diferently than tail_ though, and I'm not sure why this is.
Should I be thinking about one variable at a time (e.g. tail_ is being loaded here and stored there) or should I be thinking about one block (or function definition in this case) at a time, and seeing what happens to non atomic variables before/after a specific load or store event?
Background: I plan on using this in a two-thread logger. One thread will write std::strings to the queue, and the other will pop messages off the queue and write them to disk.
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class LockFreeQueue {
public:
    LockFreeQueue(size_t capacity) 
        : capacity_(capacity), head_(0), tail_(0), size_(0) {
        buffer_ = std::unique_ptr<std::string[]>(new std::string[capacity_]);
    }

    bool push(const std::string& msg) {
        size_t tail = tail_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        size_t next_tail = (tail + 1) % capacity_;
        if (next_tail == head_.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
            return false; // full
        }

        buffer_[tail] = msg;
        tail_.store(next_tail, std::memory_order_release);
        size_.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        return true;
    }

    bool pop(std::string& msg) {
        size_t head = head_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        if (head == tail_.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
            return false; // empty
        }

        msg = std::move(buffer_[head]);
        head_ = (head + 1) % capacity_;
        size_.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        return true;
    }

    bool empty() const {
        return head_.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == tail_.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    }

private:
    size_t capacity_;
    std::unique_ptr<std::string[]> buffer_;
    std::atomic<size_t> head_;
    std::atomic<size_t> tail_;
    std::atomic<size_t> size_;
};


AFAIK ...

We can't have a size_ member that works atomically with head_ and tail_ because all three would have to be changed in a single atomic operation.
head_ and tail_ have to (should be) updated/compared in a single atomic operation (e.g. atomic_compare_exchange*).
I'm not sure that just making each a separate atomic variable is sufficient.


When I create a ring queue, I put the head_/tail_ (i.e. enqueue/dequeue) indexes in a struct and make that atomic. That way, all access to both indexes is atomic. I also use 32 bit indexes because not all architectures support true/atomic 128 bit exchanges.
So, here is how I would refactor your code. (Side note: I usually do ring queue implementations in C, but here I've done it with C++ atomics, so please forgive any [excessive] C'isms).
Note that I've used std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong but you could replace this with (e.g.) std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit if you choose.
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

typedef int32_t qidx;

struct QueuePair {
    qidx qenq;                      // head_
    qidx qdeq;                      // tail_
};

class LockFreeQueue {
public:
    LockFreeQueue(qidx capacity,bool drop = 0) :
        capacity_(capacity), drop_(drop)
    {
        buffer_ = std::unique_ptr<std::string[]> (new std::string[capacity_]);
    }

    bool
    push(const std::string &msg)
    {
        QueuePair qnow = qnow_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        QueuePair qnext;

        while (1) {
            qnext = qnow;
            qnext.qenq = (qnext.qenq + 1) % capacity_;

            // queue full?  what to do?
            if (qnext.qenq == qnext.qdeq) {
                // just stop (and report failure)
                if (! drop_)
                    return false;

                // remove the oldest queue element to make room for the new one
                qnext.qdeq = (qnext.qdeq + 1) % capacity_;
            }

            if (std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&qnow_,&qnow,qnext))
                break;
        }

        buffer_[qnext.qenq] = msg;

        return true;
    }

    bool
    pop(std::string &msg)
    {
        QueuePair qnow = qnow_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        QueuePair qnext;

        while (1) {
            // queue empty?
            if (qnow.qenq == qnow.qdeq)
                return false;

            qnext = qnow;
            qnext.qdeq = (qnext.qdeq + 1) % capacity_;

            if (std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&qnow_,&qnow,qnext))
                break;
        }

        msg = buffer_[qnext.qdeq];

        return true;
    }

    bool
    empty() const
    {
        return size() == 0;
    }

    qidx
    size() const
    {
        QueuePair cur = qnow_.load(std::memory_order_acquire);

        qidx dif = cur.qenq - cur.qdeq;
        if (dif < 0)
            dif += capacity_;

        return --dif;
    }

private:
    std::atomic<QueuePair> qnow_;
    qidx capacity_;
    bool drop_;
    std::unique_ptr <std::string[]> buffer_;
};

